# Keycloak Behind Nginx Proxy with Http Port is not 80

Tags: nginx, keycloak

So my nginx is configured like image below

[image: nginx configuration]

so when i set the `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` to `TRUE`, it would be redirect to https://example.org:8080

what should i config on the Keycloak so it could redirect correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question here is not very clear to say the least.
But since you are having problems with nginx proxy I would suggest you set `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in your nginx conf, this way nginx will not override the Host header when proxying.
If that does not solve your problem, please provide more information about you what you want to achieve and what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mindslave. so basically my organization configures the nginx to listen http not on 80, and https not on 443, is it affect to the keycloak's wildfly server to redirect the address ??

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand your problem correctly but I think you want to use nginx as a proxy in front of Keycloak. And your having a problem getting nginx to redirect traffic to Keycloak, right?
There are 2 configuration options that you will have to set `listen` for the port nginx listens on  and `proxy_pass` for the url that nginx should proxy to, so `proxy_pass https://your-keycloak-ip:8443/` for example.
I hope that helps